# How to tell if a haskell sourcecode has Bang

Tags: haskell, ghc, hackage

Is there any library function that tells if a given .hs file uses strictness annotation? Or do I have to go into the syntax tree?

Comment: Yeah I'd recommend `haskell-src-exts` and then walking the tree.  Just looking for a particular subpattern isn't too hard...

Comment: It might be harder than that, extensions can be specified in a .cabal file as well, or by another build tool.  In practice you won't come across that often, but it is technically legal to do so.

Comment: Strictness is sometimes described in the documentation for the library (which is something you should read in any case if you plan to use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure this out with the parsers in Language.Haskell.Exts, which is from haskell-src-exts. Thanks luqui!